# Could not find gem 'sprockets (= 2.2.2.backport2) ruby' in the gems available on this machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, sprockets

I have a problem with my gemset.

I created a new one after a fresh install on my computer, just one step after cloning the repo.

Running `bundle install` but I get this error

`Could not find gem 'sprockets (= 2.2.2.backport2) ruby' in the gems available on this machine`

I'm using Rails 3.2.11 and ruby 2.1
I have followed the suggestion of the `bootstrap-sass` [Readme](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) 
But it doesn't work

Here is the part of my Gemfile with assets group

```
  group :assets do
    gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.2.3"
    gem 'compass-rails'
    gem 'sprockets-rails', '=2.0.0.backport1'
    gem 'sprockets', '=2.2.2.backport2'
    gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'
    gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.2.1"
    gem 'uglifier', '>=1.0.3'
    gem 'eco'
    gem 'i18n-js'
  end
```

The project works on other machines. What can I do?

**UPDATING THE QUESTION**

Now I have the same problem but with `rbenv`, and I don't know how to solve it because `rbenv` doesn't have gemsets!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem following these steps:

- Change the gemfile replacing the `sass-rails` gem with this one: `gem 'sass-rails', github: 'guilleiguaran/sass-rails', branch: 'backport'`
- Create and use a new empty Gemset
- Go here and download this gem [sprockets 2.2.2 backport2](https://rubygems.org/gems/sprockets/versions/2.2.2.backport2)
- Copy the downloaded gem in vendor/cache section
- run `bundle install`

This should solve the problem related to this gem `sprockets (= 2.2.2.backport2) ruby` because it will be installed by the downloaded one.

Comment: How is this different than Aliw77's solution?

Comment: Ups! You are right there is a difference but I didn't write it! I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue yesterday. A colleague of mine came across a [Twitter conversation](https://twitter.com/philipptessenow/status/528925327578644480) which points to a new fork of Sprockets with a `2.2.2.backport2`-type tag.

You can [get it on GitHub](https://github.com/tessi/sprockets/tree/2_2_2_backport2) or add it to your `Gemfile`:

`gem 'sprockets', github: 'tessi/sprockets', branch: '2_2_2_backport2'`

Comment: repo not found.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best, but I found the gem and cached it (put it in vendor/cache) based on this:  https://github.com/aliw77/sprockets-2.2.2.backport2.  I have a feeling there's another solution, still looking for it.

Comment: Thank you, although is not the solution, you inspired me to find the right one!